# Issue with dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with submenu, when i hovering on about section the dropdown menu width is more than it suppose to be. 
What i did wrong and how can fix it?
Any other suggestion related to my css code would be appreciated.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0vwhhehz/)

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-nav ul {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main-nav>ul>li {
  float: left;
}

.main-nav .active {
  background-color: #0361D6;
}

.main-nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: white;
}

.main-nav ul li {
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
  background-color: #066EFC;
}

.main-nav>ul>li {
  border-right: 1px solid #0858C5;
}

.main-nav ul>li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.main-nav li {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0B418B;
}

.main-nav li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0361D6;
  color: #C4C4C4;
}

.sub-nav ul {
  display: none;
}

.sub-nav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.sub-nav {
  padding: 0px;
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  left: 85px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
      <nav class="sub-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Company</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Workers</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you reduce the width of the submenu (assuming same as _About_) then those items will have virtually no left/right padding and will touch the left/right edges of their container. Not what you want visually. Your submenu is employing the same padding profile you provided to the top level items, which seems appropriate and should be your starting point. FWIW, you don't need to wrap the submenu `ul` in a `nav`.

Comment: Try declaring separate padding for them with `.main-nav  ul li li`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I got the **solution** which you *might be looking for*. Refer to the link below...

https://jsfiddle.net/Dhruvil21_04/x40psw2c/1/

**OR**

Replace your 4 css selctors as given below...

```
/*--------Replace-------*/

.sub-nav {
    padding: 0px;
    float:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100%;
}
.main-nav li:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color: #0361D6;
    color: #C4C4C4;
    position: relative;
}

/*--------Add-------*/

.main-nav ul ul > li {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.main-nav ul ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```